'payments' is not a registered namespace
I think I did a good job mapping the URL, so please check it out
from django.urls import path
from . import views

app_name = 'payments'

urlpatterns = [
    path('request/<int:order_id>/', views.payment_request, name='payment_request'),
    path('success/', views.payment_success, name='payment_success'),
    path('fail/', views.payment_fail, name='payment_fail'),
    path('checkout/', views.checkout_view, name='checkout'),
]

def checkout_view(request):
    return render(
        request,
        'checkout.html',
    )

<form method="post" action="{% url 'payments:checkout' %}">
    {% csrf_token %}
    {{ form.as_p }}

created app_name = 'payments'

add error trace you are getting

The reason for this problem is that you are using reverse URL in your form (action="{% url 'payments:checkout' %}"), but you didn't include your app's URLs in the project.
To solve this problem, you should include "payments.urls" in your project.
Assume your project name is "shop". In shop.urls you have to add this line in the urlpatterns:
path('', include("payments.urls")),

By doing this, Django can detect the app's URLs, and after that you can use reverse URL. Also, don't forget about putting your app name into the INSTALLED_APP.
